# Calculate last quater from today (given Fiscal Year end)

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have as input a "Fiscal Year end", which determines the quarter ends of a company. Say:

```
today() is 3-April-2015
Company fiscal year ends: Oct-14
```

then I should get the latest quarter end : `Jan-15`
i.e the latest quarter end from the company fiscal year end till today's date.

With:

```
FiscalEnd=12/02/2014
Today() (a3)  =04/03/2015
```

I have tried:

```
=TEXT(EOMONTH(Fiscal_Year_EndQ,MOD(-MONTH(A3),3)-3),"mmm-yy")
```

and am getting `Nov-14`.

Example:
Fiscal Year ends at: 31-Oct-2014
Today's date: 4 April 2015

```
List of QUARTER
aug-oct 2014
nov-jan 2015
feb-april 2015
```

So here I should get `Jan-15` as last fiscal quarter end.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
=EOMONTH(A1,-MOD(MONTH(A1)-2,3)-1)
```

formatted as `mmm-yy` may serve.

Answer (score 0):

The standard formula to give quarters is:

```
=CHOOSE(CEILING(MONTH(A1)/3,1),"Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")
```

where **A1** contains the date in question.  But your fiscal year starts on October 15th.  So this formula must be offset by the difference between January 1st and October 15th:

```
=CHOOSE(CEILING(MONTH(A1-288)/3,1),"Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")
```

**EDIT#1:**

In **A2** enter today's date.  In **B2** enter:

```
=CHOOSE(CEILING(MONTH(A2-305)/3,1),1,2,3,4)
```

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(B2-1=0,4,B2-1)
```

In **D2** enter:

```
=CHOOSE(C2,"Jan","Apr","Jul","Oct")
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: its oct (month) and 15(year).

Comment: We need the date of the first day of the fiscal year.  Is the first day of the fiscal year then **October 1 2016** ?? Or is it **November 1 2016**

Comment: basically here , i don't need any date depended, for all its would be last date of the month., and output required would be the today - (latest available quarter) in month-year

Comment: I cannot help you unless I know the first date of the fiscal year.

Comment: lets say that , 31-oct-2014 is end of the quarter. and i've also edit'd the question, check the example i've stated!!

Comment: thnks for that, but i want to give dynamic month as a quarter end.

Comment: Then we would have to replace the **305** with a short formula giving the difference between Jan 1st and the start of the fiscal year,